# Delegate Returning nil, not in ViewController but on Delegate creating class

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, fatal-error

Before flagging my problem as duplicate, please go through my question,
I have used delegate pattern in my app, and all of my code related to delegates working fine. But now there is one class that is having its delegate nil at a point which i am describing bellow.

```
//protocol class,
protocol CampaignCollectionViewCellDelegate: class {

 func campaignCollectionViewCell(_ Cell: CampaignCollectionViewCell, didContributePressed: UIButton, at indexPath: IndexPath)

 }

 // class where delegate is assigning.

class CampaignCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


weak var delegate: CampaignCollectionViewCellDelegate? = .none 

//here i am getting delegate as nil.
@IBAction func didContributeButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if self.delegate != nil {
        self.delegate?.campaignCollectionViewCell(self, didContributePressed: sender, at: self.indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

In my main class, i am doing something like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var campaignCollectionView: UICollectionView!
```

and in `viewDidLoad()`

```
campaignCollectionView.delegate = self
campaignCollectionView.dataSource = self
```

here when i debugged i got that my delegate is not nil but having some object reference in it, I have tried using this way also

```
var campaignVC = CampaignCollectionViewCell()
campaignVC.delegate = self
```

but this also didn't worked out for me, I have done same thing to all of my other delegate methods, and they are working fine, I have no idea why it is showing me behaviour like this. I have gone through every single question related to delegates but none worked for me.

Comment: You need to assign the delegate when the UICollectionViewDataSource dequeues the cell. If you still don't understand, then show your `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath` implementation

Comment: I am honoured, Thnaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cell you created here:

```
var campaignVC = CampaignCollectionViewCell()
```

is not the same cell as the ones that gets displayed in the collection view.

You need to set the `delegate` of the cells that actually get displayed in the collection view, not just any cell.

In your `cellForItemAt` method, you probably have a call to `dequeueReusableCell`:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CampaignCollectionViewCell
```

You should set the delegate straight after the above line:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CampaignCollectionViewCell
cell.delegate = self
```